# Windows Registered I/O Win 8.1 RioCreateRequestQueue Error 10045

Tags: c++, windows, sockets

Using Win8.1 and Visual Studio 2013, I’ve tested every example of Windows Registered I/O that I can find (about 5). All result in error 10045 on RioCreateRequestQueue() as shown below on one.

```
c:>rioServerTest.exe
InitialiseRio Start
InitialiseRio End
CreateCompletionQueue Start
CreateCompletionQueue End
CreateRequestQueue start
RIOCreateRequestQueue Error: 10045
```

Related code is :

```
void *pContext = 0;

printf("CreateRequestQueue start\n");

g_requestQueue = g_rio.RIOCreateRequestQueue(
    g_socket,     // Socket
    (ULONG) 10,   // MaxOutstandingReceive,
    (ULONG) 1,    // maxReceiveDataBuffers,
    (ULONG) 10,   // MaxOutstandingSend,
    (ULONG) 1,    // MaxSendDataBuffers
    g_completionQueue,   // ReceiveCQ
    g_completionQueue,   // SendCQ
    pContext);                      // SocketContect

    if (g_requestQueue == RIO_INVALID_RQ) {
        printf_s("RIOCreateRequestQueue Error: %d\n", GetLastError());
        exit(1);
    }

    printf("CreateRequestQueue End\n");
```

According to the literature that I have read, Registered I/O is intended to work with Windows 8 and later and Windows Server 2012 and later.

Can anyone explain to me via an example how to get this to work on Win8.1?    TIA

Answer (score 1):

[10045](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/ms740668(v=vs.85).aspx) is `WSAEOPNOTSUPP` the description of which is *"Operation not supported.
The attempted operation is not supported for the type of object referenced. Usually this occurs when a socket descriptor to a socket that cannot support this operation is trying to accept a connection on a datagram socket."*

So actually it's likely that the code we need to see is in fact where you create your socket.

Your socket creation code should look something like this:

```
   socket = ::WSASocket(
      AF_INET,
      SOCK_DGRAM,
      IPPROTO_UDP,
      NULL,
      0,
      WSA_FLAG_REGISTERED_IO);
```

I have some example articles (including a whole suite of RIO, UDP server designs with complete source code) [here](http://www.serverframework.com/asynchronousevents/2012/03/windows-8-registered-io-example-udp-servers.html), all of these run on all operating systems that RIO supports.

Comment: I did alter Socket code slightly to make it exactly the same as yours, but the result was the same (10045).
I have also created a project based on one of your examples, and it also results in error 10045.
Someone else has posted a similar question to mine on msdn titled:
Windows Registered I/O supported on Windows 8.1 Enterprise?
There is an example included with the post on msdn, and that also results in error 10045.
It is also perhaps noteworthy that all of the examples that I could find resulted in an error 10045 on RioCreateRequestQueue.

Comment: I upgraded to 8.1 Pro - no change.

Comment: Maybe some layered service provider (LSP) has messed up your system.

Comment: So a clean install 8.1 pro system wont run my example programs unchanged and gives 10045?

Comment: I could only find parts to your examples which I pieced together. Can you point me to a full example preferably with an exe as well? I could send you the example projects I've tested if you like. After upgrading to win 8.1 pro (in case that was problem), 10045 still resulted from all examples that I have. It wasn't a new install, but an upgrade, but that shouldn't matter.

Comment: @pindumb I ran "netsh winsock reset catalog" which I presume should fix LSP problem. Problem still there.

Comment: The page which I linked to in my answer links to each of the example server pages which ALL have full source download links at the end. A full install guarantees that whatever is broken in your current environment isn't still broken after the install - an upgrade may leave it broken.

Comment: @len. Thanks, I'll check that. I copied my exes to a usb stick and attempted to run on another pc running win 8 std. It required 2 dlls which I downloaded to the usb stick, and exes all ran OK. I tried on original pc running usb stick exes with path set to "." and the programs failed as per my original posting. I have tested other network software on original pc and all worked ok. it's only RIO I've had a problem with. Original pc with problem is an I5 second pc where it works is an I7. The programs also ran ok on I7 pc with path set to ".", so appears it only needs those dlls.

Comment: @len. I checked the download page you referred to and I had actually previously downloaded the example RIOIOCPUDPMT.exe. I've tried so many things I had forgotten. I copied that exe to the USB stick and the result was the same as for the other exes. It worked on the I7 pc but not on the I5 pc.

Comment: So, either upgrade the Win 8 machine to 8.1 to see if it still fails OR reinstall the Win 8.1 machine to see if it's something that has been installed on it that is causing the problem.

Comment: Sorry if I did not make it clear, but I only upgraded the I5 machine to Win 8.1 Pro to see if it solved the problem. From what has transpired, it appears to me to point to the I5 machine - either hardware config or O/S installation. The time required to investigate the problem is getting prohibitive. Internet speeds are also slow where I'm currently located and I'm Unsure if MS provides a re-installation of the o/s and I'm unsure whether it would be feasible given the internet speed here. That may however be what's required. Strange that only RIO highlighted whatever it is.

Comment: No, it's clear to me. IMHO you need to do a clean install of Win 8.1 on the broken machine - it doesn't look like it's a problem with your code so something must have been done on the broken machine to disable/break RIO. Nothing else to be said here.

Comment: The mentioned thread in the MSDN forums is now anwered. TDI filters can break RIO: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsdesktop/en-US/ddc2d323-b1d7-478e-b4f3-354e3743466d/windows-registered-io-supported-on-windows-81-enterprise