# What includes are needed for Winsock Registered I/O

Tags: include, winsock2

What includes are needed for Winsock Registered I/O?
I'm using Windows 10 and Visual Studio Community 2015 Update3

[MSDN Winsock Include Files](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms738562(v=vs.85).aspx) is the only thing I can find and it is *very* vague.

These are the only Winsock2 includes I can find:

```
#include <WinSock2.h>
#include <WS2tcpip.h>
#include <MSWSock.h>
#include <WS2spi.h>
#include <WS2atm.h>
#include <ws2def.h>
#include <ws2ipdef.h>
```

Unfortunately none of them seem to define any RIO functions:

```
RIOCreateCompletionQueue()
RIOCreateRequestQueue()
//and etc are undefined..
```

From what I understood starting with Windows 8.1 back in 2012 these functions shipped with the Windows SDK?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quoting from MSDN:

[RIOCreateCompletionQueue function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh448841%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

> **The function pointer to the `RIOCreateCompletionQueue` function
>   must be obtained at run time by making a call to the `WSAIoctl` function**
>   with the `SIO_GET_MULTIPLE_EXTENSION_FUNCTION_POINTER` opcode specified.
>   The input buffer passed to the `WSAIoctl` function must contain
>   `WSAID_MULTIPLE_RIO`, a globally unique identifier (GUID) whose value
>   identifies the Winsock registered I/O extension functions. **On success,
>   the output returned by the `WSAIoctl` function contains a pointer to the
>   `RIO_EXTENSION_FUNCTION_TABLE` structure that contains pointers to the
>   Winsock registered I/O extension functions**. The
>   `SIO_GET_MULTIPLE_EXTENSION_FUNCTION_POINTER IOCTL` is defined in the
>   `Ws2def.h` header file. The `WSAID_MULTIPLE_RIO` GUID is defined in the
>   `Mswsock.h` header file.

Also take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25788382/windows-registered-i-o-win-8-1-riocreaterequestqueue-error-10045). A link from that question references [this RIO implementation](http://www.serverframework.com/asynchronousevents/2012/03/windows-8-registered-io---simple-rio-polled-udp-example-server.html), containing the following example (excerpt):

```
...

inline void CreateRIOSocket()
{
   g_s = CreateSocket(WSA_FLAG_REGISTERED_IO);

   Bind(g_s, PORT);

   InitialiseRIO(g_s);
}

inline SOCKET CreateSocket(
   const DWORD flags = 0)
{
   g_s = ::WSASocket(
      AF_INET,
      SOCK_DGRAM,
      IPPROTO_UDP,
      NULL,
      0,
      flags);

   if (g_s == INVALID_SOCKET)
   {
      ErrorExit("WSASocket");
   }

   return g_s;
}

inline void InitialiseRIO(
   SOCKET s)
{
   GUID functionTableId = WSAID_MULTIPLE_RIO;

   DWORD dwBytes = 0;

   bool ok = true;

   if (0 != WSAIoctl(
      s,
      SIO_GET_MULTIPLE_EXTENSION_FUNCTION_POINTER,
      &functionTableId,
      sizeof(GUID),
      (void**)&g_rio,
      sizeof(g_rio),
      &dwBytes,
      0,
      0))
   {
      ErrorExit("WSAIoctl");
   }
}

...
```